# Parse big XML feed and split information into several models

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, xml-parsing

I have a large XML feed with student information.

```
<students>
    <student>
        <studentId>10</studentId>
        <name>Joe Doe</name>
        <location>Main street</location>
        <studyId>1001</studyId>
        <study>Business 101</study>
    </student>
    <student>
        <studentId>255</studentId>
        <name>Max Friedman</name>
        <location>Main street</location>
        <studyId>223</studyId>
        <study>Computer Science</study>
    </student>
    <student>
        <studentId>452</studentId>
        <name>Josephine Smith</name>
        <location>Clinton Dr.</location>
        <studyId>881</studyId>
        <study>English Literature</study>
    </student>
    ... (2000 more rows)
</students>
```

I want to store this information in **3 seperate models**, but I do not want to parse the XML more than once.

**The models:**

```
public class Student
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long StudentId { get; set; } // Use the Id from the feed
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long StudyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StudyId")]
    public virtual Study Study { get; set; }
}

public class Study
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long StudyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public long LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Study> Studies { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried different ways to do this, but everytime it ends up messy, ugly and totally spaghetticode.

**In pseudocode I did the following:**

```
For each student in the XML
    Create a new Student object
    Check if the Location object already exists in the DB
    If not, create the Location object
    Add the Location object to the Student object
    etc... etc...
Persist the ICollection of Students to the db
```

How can I accomplish what I want in the least amount of code?

Comment: any particular reason you aren't using the original XML format as the structure of your objects?  Can the Study and Location data for each student be the same for more than one student?

Comment: what I mean i guess is that you shouldn't have `Student` and `Study` be children of `Location`.  Both `Study` and `Location` should not specify their parents.  Instead, `Student` should contain `Study` and `Location`, and the `Study` and `Location` objects should simply be lists.